# Bulk Insert Fixed Width Text File Not Loading Properly

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, fixed-width

While trying to bulk insert a  fixed width text file into a table in MS SQL Server, the first character in each field is getting pushed by one character in each row. How do I fix this?

The data is in this format -

```
M1DR3QQ3XE954K76EC5VQ302017-06-172021-07-24            
M1DR3QQ3XE954K76EC5VQ302021-07-242021-07-24            
M1E14UR7TK502G16C89CK302017-06-172020-11-24            
M1E50UN7PH498CA8WJ1UN692017-06-172018-07-09
```

There are 700 such rows

This is the table that I have created

```
CREATE TABLE [TABLENAME(
    ROW1 [char](1) NULL,
    ROW2 [varchar](15) NULL,
    ROW3 [varchar](15) NULL,
    ROW4 [varchar](50) NULL,
    ROW5 [varchar](50) NULL,
    ROW6 [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

This is the bulk insert code that I used

```
BULK INSERT TABLENAME
FROM 'DATA FILE SOURCE'
WITH (
FIELDTERMINATOR = '',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' ,
FORMATFILE = 'FORMAT FILE SOURCE'
);
```

This is my format file

```
13.0
6
1       SQLCHAR       0       1       ""          1       Column name ""
2       SQLCHAR       0       11     ""          2       Column name ""
3       SQLCHAR       0       11     ""          3       Column Name ""
4       SQLCHAR       0       10     ""          4       Column Name ""
5       SQLCHAR       0       10     ""          5       Column Name""
6       SQLCHAR       0       12      ""          6       Column Name ""
```

I am loading all the data as varchar right now and will convert the data type later once the data is properly loaded to avoid complications during BULK INSERT.

This is the result that I am getting

```
M   1AW9F20MH32 2EW4FU4FV82 2017-06-17  2018-07-09              
    M1C56YV4MN6 44KC5FE3MU9 42018-11-0  32019-11-1  3           
     M1CC5H01WD 822DF4GX8GM 722017-06-  172018-07-  09          
      M1CY2XQ9P W154U69YG3Y N452017-06  -172018-07  -09         
       M1D12M47 DA293MU7NK4 QU692017-1  0-182018-0  7-09        
        M1DF6U9 1UM628FU3JF 7RM122017-  06-172018-  07-09       
         M1DH5G 89HM836N94J V7FU732017  -10-252018  -07-09      
          M1DK2 PX7EQ195W55 T40NG69201  7-06-17201  8-07-09     
           M1DR 3QQ3XE951DR 3QQ3XE9520  21-07-2220  21-07-24    
            M1D R3QQ3XE954K 76EC5VQ302  017-06-172  021-07-24   
             M1 DR3QQ3XE954 K76EC5VQ30  2021-07-24  2021-07-24  
              M 1E14UR7TK50 2G16C89CK3  02017-06-1  72020-11-24
```

Instead of this

```
M   1AW9F20MH32 2EW4FU4FV82 2017-06-17     2018-07-09
M       1C56YV4MN64     4KC5FE3MU9      2018-11-03     2019-11-13
M       1CC5H01WD82     2DF4GX8GM72     2017-06-17     2018-07-09
```

Note that the 6th column that I have is completely empty.. I am just adding it into the table and the format file to maintain integrity and I will be dropping the column after my data is loaded into SQL. Is this happening as the 6th column is completely empty?

How do I fix this and load the data properly?

Comment: If you're going to use a format file then have you tried removing `FIELDTERMINATOR = '',` and `ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',` from the SQL and specifying `"\r\n"` as the terminator on the last column in the format file itself?

Comment: Tried doing that too.. now it shoes this error
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)"

Comment: Well it seems that your file might be malformed in some way. Are some lines too long? Are some lines too short? Do some lines contain multi-byte characters such as Unicode encoded with UTF-8? Note that bcp and Bulk Insert are very literal - `\r\n` literally means the two characters Carriage Return and Linefeed, whereas `\n` literally means only the character Linefeed.

Comment: Yes the file does contain Unicode characters encoded with UTF-8

Comment: IS that causing the issue with the Bulk import?

Comment: If you don't specify an encoding it will assume that the database's default collation applies. Most collations are oriented toward single-byte characters, and you're only using `varchar` data types in your table, so how do you think it will handle characters outside the US-ASCII range? See also: [UTF-8 encoding support for the BCP utility and BULK INSERT Transact-SQL command in SQL Server 2014 SP2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/kb3136780-utf-8-encoding-support-for-the-bcp-utility-and-bulk-insert-transact-sql-command-in-sql-server-2014-sp2-fc6706f2-3ceb-0dc2-425e-af4da42a45a1)